# SharePoint 2013 APIs

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

Looking for somewhere that describes the differences between the SharePoint 2013 APIs, specifically I'm wondering what APIs I can use to create databases and site collections.  As far as I can tell, only the Server API or Powershell will let me do that.  I was hoping I could be proved wrong and be able to use the client object model or the REST services.  Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 0):

No only server-side OM offers these kind of operations. Both CSOM and REST are built to deal with data and services hosted within SharePoint.

Comment: Do you know of any technet articles that describe that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MSDN article which best describes what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj164060.aspx

> The largest set of APIs is in the server object model of managed
>   classes. At the level of SharePoint Foundation 2013, this object model
>   includes classes and members that enable programmatic control of the
>   basic site and list structure of SharePoint Foundation. Most of these
>   classes are in the Microsoft.SharePoint namespace. In addition, you
>   can extend almost every SharePoint Foundation component by using the
>   server object model, including workflows, alerts, Web Parts, basic
>   search, and Microsoft Business Connectivity Services (BCS). **The server
>   object model also includes an extensive set of APIs enable extensions
>   of the administration and security system of SharePoint Foundation,
>   including backup, farm health and diagnostics, logging, farm and web
>   application management, upgrade, deployment, caching, and Windows
>   PowerShell customization.**

The highlighted part is not available in other API.